# WebUSB API - Unable to listen to device events

Tags: javascript, angular, webusb

I am playing with WebUSB API for the first time. I use angular 9+ and right now I am just trying to connect to my USB mouse and listen to events when I move the mouse. I can successfully request the device and connect to the mouse however I am struggling to listen to events. Currently nothing happens after this.

Here is my code, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

BTW I am fully aware I can listen to mouse events with straight Javascript, this example is purely for testing out the WebUSB API.

**HTML**

```
<button (click)=test()>Connect</button>
```

**Component JS**

```
declare global {
  interface Navigator {
      usb: {
          getDevices(): any;
          requestDevice({}):any;
          addEventListener({}):any;
          onconnect({}):any;
      }
  }
}
 async test() {
    console.log("Test");
    let device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters:[]});
    await device.open();
    device.onconnect = (event) => {
      // Add event.device to the UI.
      console.log("EVENT",event);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as far as you will get with a USB mouse because the browser will not let a site claim the USB interface which is used for input events.

The code you've written is incorrect because it is listening for `connect` events on the `USBDevice` interface. These events are fired on the `USB` interface (specifically, `navigator.usb`) and so you want to write code like this to detect connect and disconnect:

```js
navigator.usb.addEventListener('connect', (event) => {
  console.log("Device connected", event.device);
});
navigator.usb.addEventListener('disconnect', (event) => {
  console.log("Device disconnected", event.device);
});
```

Note that these events are only fired for devices the site already has access to so you always have to start by requesting device access with `navigator.usb.requestDevice()`. The events (and `navigator.usb.getDevices()`) are useful for re-establishing connections to a device in a new session.

Comment: That make's sense. I realised that I was only listening to the connect event after checking some examples out. So assume you can listen to the usb events, after claiming I then use controlTransferOut to set channels I want to listen too and after that use transfer transferIn get the data, is this correct?

Comment: The set of transfers you need to send to the device depends on what the device supports so I can't give you much advice there without more details. Typically a device uses control transfers (sent with `controlTransferIn` and `controlTransferOut`) for configuration and bulk or interrupt transfers (sent with `transferIn` and `transferOut`) for data.